# Aggregate Query in Mongodb returns specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document Sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53329dfgg43771e49538b4567"),
    "u" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("532a435gs4c771edb168c1bd7"),
        "n" : "Salman khan",
        "e" : "salman@gmail.com"
    },
    "ps" : 0,
    "os" : 1,
    "rs" : 0,
    "cd" : 1395685800,
    "ud" : 0
}
```

Query:

```
db.collectiontmp.aggregate([
            {$match: {os:1}},
            {$project : { name:{$toUpper:"$u.e"} , _id:0 } },
            {$group: { _id: "$u._id",total: {$sum:1} }},
            {$sort: {total: -1}}, { $limit: 10 }
             ]);
```

I need following things from the above query:

1. Group by `u._id`
2. Returns total number of records and email from the record, as shown below:

   {
       "result":
       [
           {
               "email": "",
               "total": ""
           },
           {
               "email": "",
               "total": ""
           }
       ],
           "ok":
       1
   }

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first thing you are doing wrong here is not understanding how [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is intended to work. Pipeline stages such as [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will only output the fields that are "explicitly" identified. So only the fields you say to output will be available to the following pipeline stages.

Specifically here you "project" only part of the "u" field in your document and you therefore removed the other data from being available. The only present field here now is "name", which is the one you "projected".

Perhaps it was really your intention to do something like this:

```js
db.collectiontmp.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "_id": "$u._id",
           "email": { "$toUpper": "$u.e" }
        },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "email": "$_id.email",
        "total": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "total": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

Or even:

```js
db.collectiontmp.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$u._id",
        "email": { "$first": { "$toUpper": "$u.e" } }
        "total": { "$sum": 1 },
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "email": 1,
        "total": 1
    }},
    { "$sort": { "total": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 10 }
])
```

That gives you the sort of output you are looking for.

Remember that as this is a "pipeline", then only the "output" from a prior stage is available to the "next" stage. There is no "global" concept of the document as this is not a declarative statement such as in SQL, but a "pipeline".

So think Unix pipe "|" command, or otherwise look that up. Then your thinking will fall into place.

Comment: @Anubhav Unintentionally omitted by me in the course of explaining how fields are omitted if not specified. `$match` should generally always be your first stage, as that is where an index can be used. Also add at later stages for additional filtering if required.