# CSV output from mongo query

Tags: mongodb

Query Output:

```
"result" : [
            {
                "total" : 149,
                "email" : "TEST8@GMAIL.COM"
            },
            {
                "total" : 54,
                "email" : "TEST7@GMAIL.COM"
            } ...
        ],
        "ok" : 1
```

Query: [Aggregate Query in Mongodb returns specific field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419139/aggregate-query-in-mongodb-returns-specific-field)

Now I am trying to export the query output to csv file. I want to get output file as shown below:

```
total(column 1)  Email(column 2)
149              TEST8@GMAIL.COM
54               TEST7@GMAIL.COM
...
```

Please help!

Comment: The answer to this question might help.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971151/file-write-operations-in-mongo-script]

Comment: I tried this already, Giveing me this response Thu Aug 21 14:35:31.844 TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasNext'

Answer (score 0):

You could basically store the results into a different (temporary) collection and then generate csv using that collection. This could be done by adding $out field in your aggregation pipeline.

There are good examples and explanation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

-- From the link

```
$out

Takes the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline and writes them to a specified collection. The $out operator must be the last stage in the pipeline. The $out operator lets the aggregation framework return result sets of any size.
```

Comment: You started on the right note. Further a simple mongoexport on this collection will yield the required result.